Javascript canvas line graph smooth curve
I have the following graph draw from array data. I want to use plain javascript, no libraries.

How could I curve this so its not straight lines? Basically I am trying to replicate youtube video heatmap graph (most viewable times through video). Nothing fancy, just so its curved.

I am not sure if getMaxY function is accurate.




var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var values = [10, 22, 64, 9, 97, 5, 11, 45, 33, 15, 55, 19];
var width = 600;
var height = 50;

c.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height)
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(0, height);

c.lineTo(getXPixel(0), getYPixel(values[0]));

for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i ++) {
    c.lineTo(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(values[i]));
}

c.lineTo(width, height);
c.lineTo(0, height);

c.fillStyle = "rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.2)";
c.fill();



function getMaxY() {
    var max = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i ++) {
        if(values[i] > max) {
            max = values[i];
        }
    }
    max += 10 - max % 10;
    return max;
}

function getXPixel(val) {
    return (width / (values.length-1)) * val;
}

function getYPixel(val) {
    return height - ((height / getMaxY()) * val);
}
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="50" ></canvas>




You can use ctx.quadraticCurveTo function with a "look forward" control point to make the line curvy.
UPDATE: I added the previous line for comparison, we can see it's not very precise. I'll experiment with another function. Maybe bezierCurveTo will be better.
UPDATE 2: My lazy solution for a better precision is to use more points (by adding the averages between each points)


var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var values = [10, 22, 64, 9, 97, 5, 11, 45, 33, 15, 55, 19];
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

// add more points for better precision
var newValues = [values[0]]
for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
  newValues.push((values[i - 1] + values[i]) / 2)
  newValues.push(values[i])
}
values = newValues


c.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height)
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(0, height);

c.lineTo(getXPixel(0), getYPixel(values[0]));

for (var i = 1; i < values.length - 2; i++) {
  const xc = (getXPixel(i + 1) + getXPixel(i)) / 2;
  const yc = (getYPixel(values[i + 1]) + getYPixel(values[i])) / 2;
  c.quadraticCurveTo(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(values[i]), xc, yc);
}

// Draw the last segment
c.quadraticCurveTo(
  getXPixel(values.length - 2),
  getYPixel(values[values.length - 2]),
  getXPixel(values.length - 1),
  getYPixel(values[values.length - 1])
);


c.lineTo(width, height);
c.lineTo(0, height);

c.fillStyle = "rgba(244, 0, 0, 0.82)";
c.fill();
c.closePath()

// old line code, for comparison
c.beginPath();

c.moveTo(getXPixel(0), getYPixel(values[0]));

for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
  c.lineTo(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(values[i]));
}
c.stroke()
c.closePath()


function getMaxY() {
  var max = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] > max) {
      max = values[i];
    }
  }
  max += 10 - max % 10;
  return max;
}

function getXPixel(val) {
  return (width / (values.length - 1)) * val;
}

function getYPixel(val) {
  return height - ((height / getMaxY()) * val);
}
#myCanvas {
  background: gray;
}
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="150"></canvas>




If values array if large, do we need to more points for better precision? And how large would it need to be?

i think it depends on the data, if it alternates between high to low frequently, then there is a compromise between the curve and the precision. i think the example with 24 points looks ok

Would it be possible to somehow not "raise" less important parts, thus more putting more accent on important parts. For example on youtube:  https://snipboard.io/4810it.jpg  I dont know the data ofcourse, but it seems ot me that graph raises steeply towards more important parts (while leaving less important parts down).

do you mean like to "flatten" the graph? you can normalize the data i suppose if that's what you want

Can you show me example of normalize?  Would this potentialy make graph behave differently?  Currently I wish graph does not rise so much in all areas, as soon as some values are provided. I wish if I could make it raise high only in very important areas, while staying rather low in others.

I don't fully understand the required results. Maybe an example would help. Some methods: Min-Max Normalization, Logarithmic Transformation, Trimming Outliers, Percentage Change and more.

This is my problem:  https://jsfiddle.net/a3orvj6t/1/  As the number or data rises (half hour video is 1800 data points, one for each second), graph look like a mess. Is there a way to somehow average all this down? So it looks like a wave, not spikes.

use less data points, every 10 second for example

You mean log less and reduce array before drawing?

I would say about 40 data points for every 100px of graph width. experiment. in order to  reduce the array you can just take every Nth element.
